# how to hide a vertical scroll bar when not needed

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a textarea which is contained in a div as I have jquery hint and wanted to use opacity without changing the border.
There is a visible vertical scroll bar how I only want this displayed when I am typing in the text field and it goes beyond the container. I have tried overflow: auto; but does not work.

Textfield:

```
<label>
    <div id="name">
        <textarea name="message" type="text" id="message"
            title="Enter Message Here"
            rows=9 cols=60 maxlength="2000"></textarea>
    </div>
</label>
```

Styles:

```
#name { 
    border: 1px solid #c810ca;
    width: 270px;
    height:159px;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: relative;
    }

#message {
    height: 400px;
    width: 235px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS hide scroll bar if not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716863/css-hide-scroll-bar-if-not-needed)

Answer (score 223, accepted):

`overflow: auto` (or `overflow-y: auto`) is the correct way to go.

The problem is that your text area is taller than your div.  The div ends up cutting off the textbox, so even though it looks like it should start scrolling when the text is taller than `159px` it won't start scrolling until the text is taller than `400px` which is the height of the textbox.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/G9rfq/1/

I set overflow:auto on the text box, and made the textbox the same size as the div.

Also I don't believe it's valid to have a `div` inside a `label`, the browser will render it, but it might cause some funky stuff to happen.  Also your `div` isn't closed.

Comment: How to make this solution work when we have customized the scrollbar using -webkit-scrollbar psuedo element. ? because if overflow is auto psuedo elements arent working....  I want to customize my scrollbar as well as hide then when not needed ?

Answer (score 3):

`overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;` should do it I think.

Comment: As I have said in my question overflow: auto; does not work :(

Comment: hidden hides the scroll bar but once the texts passes the div it does not display the scroll bar so cannot scroll down to see rest of text

Comment: I've just tested it and it works fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: i am using firefox but in IE hidden shows the scroll bar no matter if text passes div and with auto once it passes the DIV container the scroll bar doesnt show

Comment: Try adding `position: relative;` on the `#name div`

Comment: I came up onto this : `http://www.defusion.org.uk/archives/2007/04/02/when-overflow-hidden-doesnt-hide-in-ie/`

Comment: interesting but what is the child and what is the parent?

Comment: The DIV and the TEXTAREA should not have same ID mate, I just saw. The DIV is the parent and the Textarea is the child. Let me know how you go...

Comment: Thanks I have editted my post above. can you check it pretty sure its right but its still not working :(

Comment: Not quite right :). You need to change the ID. So `<textarea name="message" type="text" id="name"` needs to be `<textarea name="message" type="text" id="NEWIDHERE"`

Comment: I'm at work don't have IE atm, but I'm more than happy to help later if still not resolved. Cheers

Comment: Your DIV tag is not closed after the textarea. Try fix that and see if it works...

Comment: @Lukus The problem is the textbox is larger than the div so it looks like it's not working.  If you typed enough text so that it exceeded the size of the textbox you would see a half a scrollbar because the other half is cut off by the div being too small to fit the textbox.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add this class in .css class

```
.scrol  { 
font: bold 14px Arial; 
border:1px solid black; 
width:100% ; 
color:#616D7E; 
height:20px; 
overflow:scroll; 
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

and use the class in div. like here.

```
<div> <p class = "scrol" id = "title">-</p></div>
```

I have attached image , you see the out put of the above code
[image]