# Adding a scroll bar to a checkbox list

Tags: html

I am using this line

```
< div id="innerTOC" style="overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden; width: 100%">
```

When I replace `'auto'` with `'scroll'` it inserts the scroll bar but is `'greyed out'` and doesn't scroll.  Is there something else I need to add?

Thanks

Comment: It turns grey if there isn't enough content to scroll it.

Comment: You should set the height of this div, so when the content is bigger, the scroll will be activated

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560330/how-to-hide-a-vertical-scroll-bar-when-not-needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your height is explicit then try to add `overflow:scroll;`

or try like this to add some `height`:-

```
<DIV style="OVERFLOW-Y:scroll; WIDTH:600px; HEIGHT:500px">
   </DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div needs to be shorter then the content of the div. Since you haven't specified a `height`, it will be as tall as it needs to be to hold all the content. Add a `height: some-length`.