# CSS hide scroll bar if not needed

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how I can hide the `overflow-y:scroll;` if not needed. What I mean is that I am building a website and I have a main area which posts will be displayed and I want to hide the scroll bar if content does not exceed the current width.

Also, my second question. I want to make it so when the posts exceed the current width, the width will increase automatically and the content won't go out of the box.

Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Posts area:

```
.content {
    height: 600px;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 19px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Main website container:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 757px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the vertical or the horizontal scroll bar? Can you post the example with html code to, e.g., http://jsfiddle.net/ and link it here

Comment: Hello, I posted the 2 classes I am using. On the html, nothing but calling classes.

Answer (score 1158, accepted):

Set `overflow-y` property to `auto`, or remove the property altogether if it is not inherited.

Comment: I could but I need some help with my second question also, about the width, auto increasing.

Comment: You can always try to use the stackoverflow search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents

Comment: Where is scroll in your examples?

Comment: While setting the ``overflow-y: auto`` solved my problem - the link does not actually show an example of this...

Comment: Should note that `overflow-x: auto` also works to hide horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 69):

You can use `overflow:auto;`

You can also control the x or y axis individually with the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties.

**Example:**

```
.content {overflow:auto;}
.content {overflow-y:auto;}
.content {overflow-x:auto;}
```

Answer (score 12):

```css
.selected-elementClass{
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: Answer doesn't add any extra value

Comment: @Akash its to the point, I like it

Answer (score 12):

overflow:auto;  used to display auto scrollbar

Comment: Same as other answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348064/2227743

Comment: Answer doesn't add any extra value

Comment: @Akash If you're certain that an answer is a copy-paste/duplicate/plagiarism, you can and should raise a custom flag. Just link to the original answer and explain your reasoning, e.g. "This answer is a duplicate because it is copied from xxx from y years ago."

Answer (score 11):

You can use both .content and .container to overflow:auto. Means if it's text is exceed automatically scroll will come x-axis and y-axis. **(no need to give separete x-axis and y-axis commonly give overflow:auto)**

> .content {overflow:auto;}

Answer (score 8):

```
.container {overflow:auto;}
```

will do the trick. If you want to control a specific direction, you should set auto for that specific axis. A.E.

```
.container {overflow-y:auto;}
.container {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

The above code will hide any overflow in the x-axis and generate a scroll-bar when needed on the y-axis. But you have to make sure that your content default height is smaller than the container height; if not, the scroll-bar will not be hidden.

Comment: Answer doesn't add any extra value