# Css rule to make x scrollbar always hidden, but y only show if needed?

Tags: css, scroll

In css, is there a rule(s) to make the x-scrollbar always hidden, but make the y-scrollbar show only if it goes past the page (i.e. only show if needed)?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS hide scroll bar if not needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716863/css-hide-scroll-bar-if-not-needed)

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
body{overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto;}
```

Answer (score 3):

this will apply to all element . so no probability of horizontal scrollbar

```
*{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

for the y use the element u want

```
body{
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

you can use any other div if u want