# Hiding scroll bar of a DIV

Tags: css

Currently I am using the following code to display scroll bar:

```
div.productsTree{
  height:300px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

While using this CSS the **scroll bars are visible all the time**, meaning even when the content inside the div doesn't overflow.

**How can I hide them when the content fits within the mentioned height?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS hide scroll bar if not needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716863/css-hide-scroll-bar-if-not-needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `overflow:auto;`. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Both x,y axis scroll
div.productsTree{
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
}

//only x axis scroll
div.productsTree{
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

//only y axis scroll
div.productsTree{
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```