# How to hide overflow scrollbar on Microsoft Chrome when there is no where to scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to hide the scroll bars for Microsoft Chrome, and only hide them when there is no where to scroll? The following div/styles always display the scroll bar, horizontal and vertical. Even when the height is larger than the content.

```
<div style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll">
  This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
</div>
```

The following hides the scroll bar:

```
::webkit-scrollbar{
   display:none
}
```

But I want them to show when there is somewhere to scroll

Is there also a way to hide only the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: "_Microsoft Chrome_"?? Do you mean you've Chrome installed on Windows?

Comment: yes Microsoft OS with Chrome

Comment: Just wanted to ask what is Microsoft Chrome

Comment: use `auto` instead of `scroll` to let scrollbar show only when something is scrollable. and if you don't need the scrollbar at all remove `overflow` property at all.

Comment: `::webkit-scrollbar{
   display:none
}` hides all scrollbars on webkit browsers (chrome on Windows and Linux and all browsers on macOS) you shouldn't use that

Comment: yes that is what i said in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `overflow-y` property and set it to `auto` to enable the vertical scrollbar when it's needed.

Set `overflow-x` to `hidden` to disable horizontal scrolling altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain your code, you have mentioned the height for your container so whenever the content exceeds that it shows up the scroll bar. If you remove those there won't be a scroll bar.

Else mentions `overflow: auto` so that when it exceeds the specific height it shows up the scroll bar. Here's the code below if you go full size there won't be a scroll bar.

```css
div{
background: red; width: 200px;overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div >
  This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
</div>
```

Now in the case of horizontal and vertical, there were CSS rules specific to that. **overflow-x** and **overflow-y**

To hide the horizontal bar .. here you go ;)

```css
   .vertical-scroll{
     width:100px;height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x:hidden;}
```

```html
<h1>Hide horizontal scroll</h1>
           <div class="vertical-scroll" >
            This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
          </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Set `overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: auto;` on div, it shows scrollbars only if they are needed. (From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716863/css-hide-scroll-bar-if-not-needed))
So your final code should look like:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
::webkit-scrollbar{
   display:none
   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: auto;">
  This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```