# Why is the vertical scrollbar always visible

Tags: javascript, css, html, d3.js

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q3MpeDT2rSSCUy8CHdUa?p=preview

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 100px;                   
    height: 500px;                  
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

When you hover the mouse on one of the circles, a tooltip with vertical scrollbar is always visible even when the height is more than enough for the content.  Why is vertical scroll always visible.  How and I make it show up only when the content actually overflows?

Comment: `div.tooltip` has a css property of `overflow-y:scroll;`. This causes the scrollbar to always show. You should change it to `overflow-y:auto;`. This will cause it to show only when needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to hide a vertical scroll bar when not needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560330/how-to-hide-a-vertical-scroll-bar-when-not-needed)

Comment: Thanks guys.  I got confused by the meaning.  I thought overflow-y: scroll to mean show scroll when overflow happens :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just change `overflow-y:scroll` to `overflow-y:auto;`